# How do you deal damage to your opponent's nexus in Dominion?

Tags: league-of-legends

I know that you damage the opponent's nexus by controlling more capture points than they do. And I think I recall from the one game I played last night that there were other actions that did this as well, like killing enemy champions.

I'm also curious about the rate at which nexus health decreases when you control 3, 4 and 5 bases.

**What are all the ways to damage the opposing team's nexus, and how much damage do each of these actions deal?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From what I have read and played, the following actions decrease nexus health :

- Controlling more capture points than opponents decreases Nexus life over time (x damage per 5 seconds for each point you control **IF** you control more points then enemies)
- Killing an Enemy champion deals immediate damage (-2 life to nexus if nexus life is above 100)
- Achieving a secondary objective (quest) deals immediate damage (-20 life to nexus) and gives your team a buff (like Nashor in normal mode, except not the same buff).
  Those secondary quests appear randomly and consist of capturing a specific capture point. These quest spawn for both teams at the same time and always concern two Capture points next to another.
- Point Neutralization and point capture (-3 and -2 life to nexus if nexus life is above 100)

Comment: For what it's worth, yesterday I was playing a game and the enemy only had 5 life left on their nexus.  I killed a player and their nexus life remained the same.  Kills may not count beyond a certain score or time - I can't say for sure

Comment: Quests deal 20 damage. Neutralizing a point (returning it from enemy control) deals 3 damage to the enemy, but I think this loss is throttled in the same way that champion deaths eventually stop counting.

Comment: Killing an Enemy champion deals no damage if the Enemy Nexus has less than 100 health remaining.

Comment: Raven is correct. 20 dmg is dealt to the enemy nexus when you fulfill each of the two quests that will show up (often 1 capture, 1 defend).

Comment: @Kaze - that's not how quests work.

Comment: Capturing a point for your team deals 2 damage. Like champion kills & point neutralization, this effect is throttled once enemy Nexus life is sufficiently low.

Comment: Edited with the new information.

Answer (score 3):

### The following actions always apply:

- Holding the *majority* of capture points: **X Damage per tick**, where X is the number of capture points you control. <sup><sub>(regardless of how many capture points are owned or neutral.)</sub></sup>
- Completing a quest: **20 Damage**

### The following only deal damage if the opponent's nexus is at or above 100 health:

- Killing an Enemy champion: **2 Damage**
- Point Neutralization: **3 Damage**
- Point Capture: **2 Damage**

Comment: It's the same information in @Dalshim's answer but formatted in such a way that I can reference this quickly during a game. I thought it would be too much of a change to put in an edit. If I was wrong about that please let me know and I will delete this answer.

Comment: Also, does anyone have any data on how long a "tick" is? Does it ever change?

Comment: Tick would apparently be 5 seconds, but damage doesn't occure every 5 seconds. 1 damage is done every 5/x seconds (where x = number of owned points if you have majority)

Comment: Tested yesterday, what I said on previous comment is wrong. x point are taken on each tick, but ticks seemed to be shorter than 5 seconds (more like 3 seconds, but I didn't measure)